# Problema com SWF

Tags: html, flash

Tenho um arquivo em swf e não consigo de maneira alguma colocar ele em uma página.
Já tentei de todas as maneiras e não funciona .. o problema é que esse swf é um tour virtual e o cliente quer porque quer ele ..

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// <![CDATA[ 
var so = new SWFObject("twviewer.swf", "sotester", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "#FFFFFF"); 
so.addParam("allowNetworking", "all"); 
so.addParam("allowScriptAccess", "always"); 
so.addParam("allowFullScreen", "true"); 
so.addParam("scale", "noscale"); 
//<!-%% Share Mode %%->
so.addVariable("lwImg", ""); 
so.addVariable("lwBgColor", "255,255,255,255"); 
so.addVariable("lwBarBgColor", "255,255,255,255"); 
so.addVariable("lwBarColor", "255,0,255,0"); 
so.addVariable("lwBarBounds", "160,180,480,8"); 
so.addVariable("lwlocation", "0"); 
so.addVariable("lwShowLoadingPercent", "true"); 
so.addVariable("lwTextColor", "255,0,0,0"); 
so.addVariable("iniFile", "config_Project36.bin"); 
so.addVariable("progressType", "0"); 
so.addVariable("swfFile", ""); 
so.addVariable("percentType", "0"); 
so.addVariable("sizeFile", "filesize.txt"); 
so.addVariable("href", location.href); 
so.write("flashcontent"); 
// ]]> 
</script>
```

Comment: Poderia postar o código que você já testou?

Comment: Editei a pergunta acima com o código!

Comment: Descreva qual ambiente não funciona. É windows, linux, mac, ios, android? Qual versao do flash? Qual versáo do player e o navegador?

Comment: Acredito que a resposta do @leonardopessoa deva lhe ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Você já tentou em HTML puro com a tag `object`?

```
<object width="400" height="50" data="meu_flash.swf"></object>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_object.asp